# Properties file in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, properties, selenium-webdriver, properties-file

i want to use my file.properties in my class test selenium web driver
so my file.properties below:

```
Selenium.test.label1=User name
Selenium.test.label2=Pass word
Selenium.test.url=my/path/url
```

my class test below

```
public class SeleniumTest{
 private WebDriver driver;
    /************ File properties configuration ***************/
    // Get the inputStream
    final InputStream inputStream =
            this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("messages_fr.properties");
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    // load the inputStream using the Properties
    properties.load(inputStream);
    /*********** End configuration properties file **************/

@before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
        final Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        this.baseUrl =
                properties.getProperty(myurl);
    }
@Test
public void firefoxTest() throws Exception {
   this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   testSelenium();
   verifyLabel(this.properties.getProperty(Selenium.test.label1,"UN");
   verifyLabel(this.properties.getProperty(Selenium.test.label2,"PW");
}
private void verifyLabel1(final String expectedLabel, final String label) {
        final WebElement element = this.driver.findElement(By.id(label));
        final String actualLabel = element.getText();
        assertEquals("Name of label:", actualLabel, expectedLabel);
    }
private void action() throws Exception{
      driver.findElement(By.id("id1").sendkeys(this.properties.getProperty("selenium.test.url"));
```

}

i have a problem in this line `properties.load(inputStream);` Syntax error on token "inputStream", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

so can some one help me to use my properties file in my class test!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me it static and call your init code in the static block

```
static final Properties properties = new Properties();

static {
    /************ File properties configuration ***************/
    // Get the inputStream
    final InputStream inputStream =
            SeleniumTest.class.getResourceAsStream("messages_fr.properties");
    System.out.println("InputStream is: " + inputStream);
    // load the inputStream using the Properties
    properties.load(inputStream);
    /*********** End configuration properties file **************/
}
```

Comment: when i do that i have this error Cannot use this in a static context and when i remove this i have this error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object

Comment: Use SeleniumTest.class.getResourceAsStream("messages_fr.properties")

Comment: Check what's loaded in th inputStream. Looks like it can't find the file

Comment: when i do it i have a different error in line properties.load(inputStream); Unhandled exception type IOException so i do that : `try { properties.load(inputStream); } catch (final IOException _e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block _e.printStackTrace(); }` and when i compile my code i have error getProperty(selenium.test.label1) give `null` not `User name`

Comment: when i tried to use the code "File properties configuration" insied firefoxTest() method it works great and my file is correctly loaded but i need to use my file properties not only inside firefoxTest() method this is the problem. so i dont think that the is the problem of file loaded

Comment: Thank you i tried to make my file in the same package to my class test it works

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method which runs once before any of the testcase is executed using  [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html)

```
  public class SeleniumTest {
    // private WebDriver driver;
    /************ File properties configuration ***************/
    final static Properties properties = new Properties();

    @BeforeClass
    static public void init() {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            // Get the inputStream
            inputStream = SeleniumTest.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("messages_fr.properties");
            System.out.println("InputStream is: " + inputStream);

            // load the inputStream using the Properties
            properties.load(inputStream);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (null != inputStream) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*********** End configuration properties file **************/
    //        ...... your rest of code......

 }
```

Comment: i have error init method must be static and setUp method

Comment: yes, because a method annotated with @BeforeClass should be static